# Spark job server throwing Out of memory when uploading jar

Tags: apache-spark

Trying to upload a jar built using maven shaded plugin to spark job server results in following error.

> job-server[ERROR] Uncaught error from thread [JobServer-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] shutting down JVM since 'akka.jvm-exit-on-fatal-error' is enabled for ActorSystem[JobServer]
>   job-server[ERROR] java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
>   job-server[ERROR]   at akka.util.ByteString$ByteStrings.compact(ByteString.scala:253)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser.entity(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:210)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser.parseFixedLengthBody(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:124)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser$$anonfun$parseFixedLengthBody$3.apply(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:129)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser$$anonfun$parseFixedLengthBody$3.apply(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:129)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser$$anonfun$needMoreData$2.apply(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:215)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.parsing.HttpMessagePartParser$$anonfun$needMoreData$2.apply(HttpMessagePartParser.scala:215)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.server.RequestParsing$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(RequestParsing.scala:87)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.can.server.RequestParsing$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$2.apply(RequestParsing.scala:85)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.ConnectionTimeouts$$anon$2$$anon$1$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(ConnectionTimeouts.scala:56)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.ConnectionTimeouts$$anon$2$$anon$1$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(ConnectionTimeouts.scala:55)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicPipelines$class.process(Pipelines.scala:50)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.ConnectionTimeouts$$anon$2$$anon$1.process(ConnectionTimeouts.scala:39)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicPipelines$$anonfun$eventPipeline$1.apply(Pipelines.scala:48)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicPipelines$$anonfun$eventPipeline$1.apply(Pipelines.scala:48)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.PreventHalfClosedConnections$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$connected$1.apply(PreventHalfClosedConnections.scala:30)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.PreventHalfClosedConnections$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$connected$1.apply(PreventHalfClosedConnections.scala:25)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicEventPipeline$SwitchableEventPipeline.apply(Pipelines.scala:79)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicEventPipeline$SwitchableEventPipeline.apply(Pipelines.scala:78)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.TickGenerator$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$1.apply(TickGenerator.scala:41)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.TickGenerator$$anon$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$1.apply(TickGenerator.scala:38)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.RawPipelineStage$$anon$3$$anonfun$2.apply(Pipelines.scala:115)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.BackPressureHandling$$anon$2$$anon$1$$anon$3$$anonfun$eventPipeline$1.apply(BackPressureHandling.scala:122)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.BackPressureHandling$$anon$2$$anon$1$$anon$3$$anonfun$eventPipeline$1.apply(BackPressureHandling.scala:103)
>   job-server[ERROR]   at spray.io.DynamicPipelines$class.process(Pipelines.scala:50)
>   job-server ... finished with exit code 255

I am starting my job server with following setting 
"re-start config/local.conf --- -Dspray.can.parsing.max-content-length=200m"

Command used to upload jar

curl --data-binary @uber-BestSelling-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar localhost:8090/jars/bestseller

Spark jobs tests and word count works well but my custom jar fails to get uploaded.

Comment: have you tried giving more memory to the spark-job-server runtime? It needs to load that file in memory first.

Comment: added --- -Xmx2g to my restart command to solve upload issue

Comment: how big is the jar, how big is the cluster?

Comment: 72.9 MB and its a small cluster in my Mac. Setting up in openstack with a relative bigger cluster to see how this scales.

Answer (score 0):

You should modify the spray-can HTTP server `parsing.max-content-length` setting to allow larger files to be uploaded:

In the following example I increased the max-content-length to 100MB:

`spray.can.server {
      parsing.max-content-length = 100m
    }`

Instructions for configuring the spray-can HTTP server are available here:
http://spray.io/documentation/1.1.2/spray-can/configuration/